# Julia Sorting dictionary with fields of a DataType

Tags: julia

I am wondering how to sort a dictionary with a particular fieldname of a datatype

For example, if I have dictionary containing objects from a struct `Casualty` how do I  sort by the fieldname `dist_from_IZ`

```
mutable struct Casualty <: AbstractAgent
    id::Int 
    ts::Int
    rescued::Bool
    dist_from_IZ::Float64 

    function Casualty(id,ts; rescued = false, dist_from_IZ = NaN)
        new(id,ts,rescued,dist_from_IZ)
    end
end
```

```
cas1 = Casualty(1, 2,dist_from_IZ = 10)
cas2 = Casualty(2, 2, dist_from_IZ = 3)
cas3 = Casualty(3, 3, dist_from_IZ = 11)  

cas_dict = Dict(1 => cas1, 2 => cas2, 3 => cas3)

sort(collect(cas_dict), by x -> x.dist_from_IZ)
# MethodError
```

What I am after is the sorted value of `id` based on `dist_from_IZ`, in this example the answer would be [2,1,3]

If I had to do this using a couple of line of code it would be ...

```
id_distance =  [(k,v.dist_from_IZ) for (k,v) in cas_dict]
id_distance_sorted= sort(id_distance, by = x -> x[2])
id_sorted = [i[1] for i in id_distance_sorted]
>>>
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 1
 3
```

but I am hoping there is a better way to use the `sort()` function straight away.

Comment: Could you please insert an expected output by providing a minimal example?

Comment: Do you already have them in a `Dict` for some other reason, or is the `Dict` just for this purpose?

Comment: Its in the form of `Dict` in the actual code I am writing currently, but perhaps I can change it

Comment: If you have a `Dict` for some other reason, and this sorting is just to get the `id` values, you probably don't need to change it. I've edited the answer to return `id`s directly too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal `Dict` doesn't have a fixed order to it. So `sort` doesn't apply to it. But here, since you do a `collect` on the dictionary first, it gets turned into  a `Vector` of individual key-value `Pair`s, which is *probably* not what you want. You *can* sort that with:

```
julia> sort(collect(cas_dict), by = p -> p.second.dist_from_IZ)
3-element Vector{Pair{Int64, Casualty}}:
 2 => Casualty(2, 2, false, 3.0)
 1 => Casualty(1, 2, false, 10.0)
 3 => Casualty(3, 3, false, 11.0)
```

but if you explain your goal and the problem you're trying to solve a bit more, there's probably a more appropriate solution, whether with [StructArrays](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StructArrays.jl), [OrderedDict](https://juliacollections.github.io/DataStructures.jl/stable/ordered_containers/)s, or [SortedDict](https://juliacollections.github.io/DataStructures.jl/stable/sorted_containers/#SortedDict-constructors-1)s.

*Edit*: Based on the edit to the question:

```
julia> [cas.id for cas in sort(collect(values(cas_dict)), 
                               by = cas -> cas.dist_from_IZ)]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 1
 3
```

Comment: May I know what `.second` does ?  Is it accessing the keys of the dict??

Comment: No, after the `collect`, there's no `Dict` anymore, all `sort` sees is a simple vector of `Pair` values. Given a single key-value `Pair` called `p`, `.second` accesses the value part of it.